# Remove margin from ListView item background

Tags: android, android-listview, android-theme, android-styles

I'm working on a theme that styles my application's ListViews by setting `android:listSelector` to a selector I've written:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_selected" />
</selector>
```

This changes the background that is shown behind individual list items/rows when pressed or selected.  In this case, listitem_pressed is a 9-Patch PNG and listitem_selected is an XML drawable that defines a gradient.  This works but I've noticed that the gradient takes all of the space available to it, while the PNG has a 4 or 5 pixel margin around it.

Where is that margin coming from and why does the PNG behave differently than the XML drawable?  Is there an easy way to get rid of it?  If possible, I would like to be able to style my application using only the theme (specified at the application level, in the manifest,) without needing to style individual ListView instances, override `ListAdapter.getView()`, etc.

Comment: If you don't explicitly define the content area in a 9-patch, then the system implicitly defines it using the patch area, and sets it's padding accordingly. If you want to disable the padding, then explicitly define the content area to include the whole drawable area.

Comment: @corsair992 Thanks.  I turned out that the 9-patch actually had a margin built into it but your advice still helped.  When I removed the margin, I found that the background was "escaping" its bounds and overlapping with other list items.  Explicitly setting the content area fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the issue I was running into was partially due to something I didn't realize about the PNG that I was given (it had whitespace around the border,) once I removed that, I ran into another issue where the background was actually overlapping with other list items.  The advice Corsair992 gave me addressed that:

Instead of relying on Android's defaults for a drawable's margin and content area, specifying the content area in the 9 Patch fixed it.